# How to return list of column header by matching values for all row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am able to print list of column header for every row if the value is above 0 using pandas, I have followed STO to solve this :

```
cols = df1.columns
bt = df1.apply(lambda x: x > 0)
print(bt.apply(lambda x: list(cols[x.values]), axis=1))
df_boolean = df1>0
```

The output looks like below:

```
AFG  Afghanistan                  
               [BEL, CZE, DNK, IRL, NLD, NOR, POL, SAU, GBR]

AGO  Angola  
               [FRA, ITA, PRT, CHE, GBR]
AIA  Anguilla   
               []
```

Now I want to print list of column header from excel file for every row based on matching values, but I can't check for a specific value since they differ randomly, there could be more than one matching values in a row and for these matching value their corresponding header name should be returned.

What I want is to return list of column header if they have matching value for every particular row.

I have found answers for different case on internet but not for checking cells value for equality.

The output should be similar to the above one.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please supply a **[mcve]**. In this case, you need to **show** us an extract of your input dataframe and your desired output.

Comment: please post your sample dataframe and  expected output

Comment: The dataframe contain countries name as column header and row header, the cells are filled with numbers.                                              The expected output looks like below:        ['BEL,CZE,DNK,IRL,NLD,NOR,POL,SAU,GBR']
['FRA,ITA,PRT,CHE,GBR']
['BEL,CZE,FIN,DEU,GRC,MKD,POL,SVN,SWE,GBR']
['AUT,BEL,CZE,FRA,IRL,NLD,NOR,POL,PRT,ESP,CHE,GB']
['AZE,BGR,CZE,DNK,FIN,FRA,IRQ,IRL,NLD,NOR,POL,SWE,TUR']

Comment: The input dataframe looks like this: